# Does GDALWarp not support writing MBTiles?

Tags: gdalwarp, mbtiles

I'm trying to create MBTiles from GeoTIFF datasets (UTM33 projection). I have tried the following command

```
gdalwarp -of MBTiles -t_srs EPSG:3857 -co "QUALITY=80" tiffs\*.tif 
dataset.mbtiles
```

The result is this error:

```
ERROR 6: Could not find an appropriate zoom level that matches raster pixel 
size
Open GDAL Datasets:
1 N MBTiles      -1 65701x77489x3 C:\Data\Testdata\dataset.mbtiles
```

I also tried to warp each TIF to EPSG:3857 and then creating a .vrt first, and then the following command:

```
gdalwarp -of MBTiles -co "QUALITY=80" tiffs.vrt dataset.mbtiles
```

with the exact same result.

I'm completely unable to get it to work, even though the [GDAL documentation for the MBTiles driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mbtiles.html) explicity says that it should work ("The driver implements the Create() and IWriteBlock() methods, so that arbitrary writing of raster blocks is possible, **enabling the direct use of MBTiles as the output dataset of utilities such as gdalwarp**.")

So the question is, am I missing something in my commands or is GDALWarp and MBTiles simply not supported in GDALWarp?

Comment: Don't have an answer other than to just use GDAL_TRANSLATE and GDALADDO

Comment: I don't fully agree that this question has been answered, but I think it was more appropriate as an issue in the GDAL GitHub. https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1160 Even Rouault responded that GdalWarp is generally not able to automatically resample raster data to a pre-defined tiling scheme. This clarification has now been added to the GPKG driver doc page.